# Unexpected URL concatenation

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a url for product categories

```
url(r'^(?P<cat>[^/]+/$)', 'reviews.views.category'),
```

for example, if I am in the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and click on "eletronics" in the menu, I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/eletronics/`
If I click again in other category (e.g. "books"), I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/eletronics/books/`
How I set up my url in way that I just get one (the last clicked) category in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu links in your template may be pointing to "electronics/" and "books/" vs "/electronics" and "/books."  To conform with DRY, I recommend [naming your url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) and using the `{% url %}` template tag to load the correct url route.

For example:

```
url(r'^(?P<cat>[^/]+/$)', 'reviews.views.category', name='category'),
```

And in your template:

`{% url 'category' 'books' %`}

Which will return the correct '/books' url route.